# Python 2.7 How to come out from ... to >>>

Tags: python, python-2.7

In python what should I do to come out from while block

```
>>>a=5
>>>while(a<=5):
...    print a
```

[while](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tBVl.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "come out from "..." to >>>"? What have you tried?

Comment: coming out from while block?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press `enter` twice. That will finish your input and Python will start executing. You have an infinite loop, though, so it'll just keep printing `5`. To stop it, press CTRL-C. Then you're at `>>>` again.

Comment: Why? Didn't it answer the question? I might still not be familiar enough with SO, is there a guideline about this?